# With "an" or without "an" before additional : an additional units

Tags: articles

> 1. **An** additional 550 units are to be built in other settlements in the West Bank.
> 2. Additional 550 units are to be built in other settlements in the West Bank.

Usually, *an* or *a* is definitely not required before plural noun. But it seems I should choose option (1) here. Why?

Comment: The word _additional_ functions as an attribuitive modifier, as an answer to your previous question explains. Moreover, _additional_ and _extra_ are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, "additional" represents a single instance of addition, therefore it is grammatical to include "an", even though the noun itself is in its plural form.

Comment: Can I delete "an"?

Comment: No, while removing it doesn't mean the sentence is not understandable it does make it ungrammatical.  Option 2 would be rarely used, if ever, and maybe only in the context of short/informal headlines e.g. on a news headline.

Comment: @david_c - Absolutely. And the rest of headline would be similarly shortened as well: _Additional 550 Units to Be Built in West Bank Settlements_